# How to check if any DTD\DOCTYPE declaration is present in an XML?

Tags: java, xml, dtd

I am trying to write a utility class through which I will find out if there is any DTD\DOCTYPE declaration is present in an XML or not.

Currently I am using LexicalHandler.startDTD(), LexicalHandler.startEntity() callback methods to check the same. 
Adding loggers in those methods to verify if its getting called or not. 
I want to know if there is any better approach to do it In Java. Could you please help me on that ?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Wanted to know the same :)..is that approach fine or there is a better approach ?

Comment: If it ain't broke don't fix it :)